# Error in code of extension for Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

can you help me with this exercise, please?

How can I play a typed value in an input of my extension in google search input?
It's an extension to chrome, I made one more mistake:

Ty

Error: 
Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' 'self'". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

```js
$(function(){
 $('#buttonSearch').click(function(){
  $('#lst-ib').text($('#name').val());
 })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Hello</title>
     <!-- <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *"> Not Work-->
  <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  
 </head>
 <body>
  <h1 id="greet">Hi</h1>
  <input type="text" id="name"/>     
  <input type="button" value="escreve" id="buttonSearch" onClick="" />
 </body>
</html>
```

Manifest.json

```html
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Hello World",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Tsste.",
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon/sound.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
 "default_icon": "icon/sound.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions":[
    "storage"
  ],

  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' object-src 'self'"
}
```

I've tried several options spread over the internet, and have not been successful.

Thank you

Comment: doesn't the error tell you exactly what to do? `Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.`

Comment: Yes, but how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

How about this

[before]

```
<input type="button" value="escreve" id="buttonSearch" onClick="" />
```

[after]

```
<input type="button" value="escreve" id="buttonSearch"/>
```